# JPA inserir um objeto que tem um list como atributo

Tags: java, mvc, jpa

estou desenvolvendo um sistema em camadas(pacotes),para exercitar os conceitos de aula e me deparei com uma dúvida Eu gostaria de criar uma classe produto,a mesma possui atributos que são referencias de outras classes :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private float preco;
private String nome;
private int qtd;
@ManyToMany
private List<Fornecedor> fornecedor;
@ManyToOne
private Categoria categoria;
```

Na minha camada em que é semelhante a DAO seguindo o conteúdo da aula teria que persistir todas as classes relacionadas no caso Fornecedor e categoria alem da classe do produto que é a que queremos criar.

```
public Produto inserir(Produto produto,List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores ,Categoria categoria) { 
    listaFornecedores=new ArrayList<>();
    Conexao con = new Conexao();
    EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(listaFornecedores);
    em.persist(categoria);
    em.persist(produto); 
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return produto;

}
```

Ops : Os parâmetros são para referenciar os objetos que já estão instanciados afim de destacar é aquele objeto (valor) que quero colocar no meu produto ou seja a categoria daquele meu objeto vou receber como parâmetro e meu produto terá aquela categoria Classe teste :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Categoria cat = new Categoria("Viajem", "nao to afim de escrever hehe");

    Fornecedor fornecedor = new Fornecedor( "Alimentos",  122354,"Alimentos@gmail.com" );

    List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores =new ArrayList<>();

    listaFornecedores.add(fornecedor);

     Produto produto = new Produto(50,"Talco",3 ,listaFornecedores,cat);

     ProdutoRN produtoRN=new ProdutoRN();

     produtoRN.inserir(produto, listaFornecedores, cat);
}
```

Entretanto da um erro em que eu não posso persistir uma lista,mas então como posso representar um produto que possui varios fornecedores

List fornecedores
ERRO

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown
>   entity: java.util.ArrayList
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:786)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:767)
>       at sistemavendas.rn.ProdutoRN.inserir(ProdutoRN.java:20)
>       at sistemavendas.TesteProduto.main(TesteProduto.java:22) Desde já grato a atenção

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `persist` da class `EntityManager` espera uma entidade (classe anotada com `@Entity`) como argumento, mas no trecho `em.persist(listaFornecedores)` você está passando um `ArrayList` que, embora contenha, não é uma entidade. Por isso a exceção.

Para persistir a lista de fornecedores, você deve invocar o método `persist` para cada fornecedor, exemplo:

```
public Produto inserir(Produto produto,List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores ,Categoria categoria) { 
    listaFornecedores=new ArrayList<>();
    Conexao con = new Conexao();
    EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for(Fornecedor fornecedor : listaFornecedores) {
        em.persist(fornecedor);
    }
    em.persist(categoria);
    em.persist(produto); 
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return produto;
}
```

Caso esteja utilizando Java 8 ou maior, você pode fazer dessa outra forma:

```
public Produto inserir(Produto produto,List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores ,Categoria categoria) { 
    listaFornecedores=new ArrayList<>();
    Conexao con = new Conexao();
    EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    listaFornecedores.forEach(em::persist);
    em.persist(categoria);
    em.persist(produto); 
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return produto;
}
```